# PHP files are downloaded by browser instead of processed by Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

when i try to run my project it download a file with the following code. i don't know what is the reason behind this. please kindly guide me about this problem

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *

 * @package  Laravel
 * @author  
 Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>

*/

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
 Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| 
Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application.
 We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't 
have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on.
 It feels nice to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 
Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| 
We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and g
ets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| 
the responses back to the browser and delight
 our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 
Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| 
Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and 
send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the 
creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared 
for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(

$request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: I think few extensions are missing https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/installation

Comment: I believe php env is missing in your system, have you installed php?

Comment: Respect sir, many of my Laravel project are already running on my system. i download my project and i try to run it on my local host and new hosting server so when i hit the URL it downloaded a file. with following code which i already most

Comment: i have env file in my project

Comment: do you get any error if you enter wrong url of the project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your server configuration is not setup to execute .php files as php scripts, but rather just display the contents as plain text. Check the configuration of your server.

Comment: Bro many of my Laravel projects are already running on my system. i download my project and i try to run it on my local host and new hosting server so when i hit the URL it downloaded a file..

Answer (score 1):

#### Apache

You need to add index.php in dir.conf

```
cat  /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf
```

Settings

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
   DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm
</IfModule>
```

Finally, restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Reference: How to setup php app, on Ubuntu 14.0 or Ubuntu 16.0
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04